# Meaning of `depuded` in `npm`

Tags: npm, npm-install

What's the meaning of `depuded` in `npm`?

When I install something after upgrading npm through `npm install -g npm` dependencies have a label text with them as `depuded`.

[image: depuded]

Answer (score 0):

In short, it means that some/all of the dependencies were duplicated during the upgrade, and then removed after being duplicated. Or, while upgrading duplicate copies of dependencies were found and removed. Deduplication is the removal of duplicated data.